# How to pass argument in callback function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, callback

I want get email (text value from txtEmail field) in callback

I have text field :

```
  <asp:TextBox MaxLength="50" runat="server" ID="txtEmail" ClientIDMode="Static" onblur="SendRequest()"></asp:TextBox>
```

my javascript handler :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function SendRequest(arg) {
           window.UseCallback(arg);
      }
 </script>
```

and server event handler

```
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string cbReference = Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "arg", "GetEmailFromServer", "context");
    string cbScript = "function UseCallback(arg, context){" + cbReference + ";}";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "UseCallback", cbScript, true);
 }

 public void RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArg)
 {
     var result = Controller.CheckEmail(eventArg);      // eventArg == undefined
 }
```

How can I set eventArg to txtEmail.Text ?

Answer (score 0):

Change This Line and Check

```
 string cbScript = "function UseCallback(arg){" + cbReference + ";}";
```

**or**  change this

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
       function SendRequest(arg) 
        {
             window.UseCallback(arg,"");
        }   
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't get how can it help me? What should I put there?

Comment: have you tried this...function UseCallback(arg, context){" + cbReference + ";} will be defined in script block of your Page,as it is taking two parameters but you are passing one...so try passing two parameters